# Advice for IPA recipe (with dry mouthfeel)

Tags: rice-hulls

I have a very simple IPA recipe with a twist which I really liked. 
It's a single malt (Pale malt, 7EBC Full-grain), 
single hop IPA, but I 'dryhopped' it with tea.

Single temperature mash @ 66C/150F, for 60 minutes
OG:1070Gr/l, 
Yeast is dry Safale US05. One package (11.5gr) on a 19L batch.
don't have my notes here but I think FG was between 1018 or such.

I would like to tweak the recipe in order to achieve a more 'dry' or crisp mouthfeel and flavor (less 'sticky', sugary, syrupy, 'full', malty).

I suspect that would allow the tea flavour to come out and shine a bit more. 
What are some approaches to consider?

- mash at lower temps (which temps? any specific advice, schedules would be a great help, etc)
- replace % of the malts with rice? (like kuhnhenn double rice IPA)
- replace % of the malts with sugar or syrup?
- use a different yeast with higher attenuation? Which ones?

are some of the approaches I've read about, but I'm unsure. 
Any of these a good idea? Are there other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it would help if we knew what mash temp and procedure you're using, but I'll take a stab at it....

mash at 146 for 90 min.

rice hulls have no fermentables, so you can't replace malt with them.  You could replace maybe 10-15% of the malt fermentables with rice, corn, or sugar

a different yeast could help a lot.  S-04 IMO isn't very good for dry beers.  If you want to stay with dry yeast, try US-05.

make sure you pitch enough yeast for the beer (what's the batch size and OG?) and give it plenty of time to ferment out

Comment: whoops, I see that I made a few mistakes, yeast used was US-05, not four. I'll add the rest of the recipe.

Comment: OK, 05 is about as attenuative as it gets.  In addition attenuation is based more on wort fermentability than yeast strain used.  The same yeast can get anywhere from 70%-90% attenuation depending on the wort.  Given that, I recommend replacing 10% (as a start) of the malt with rice, corn, or sugar.  That's given as a % of fermentables, not weight.

Comment: Given the info in your edit, the first thing I'd do is check my thermometer to be sure it's accurate.  If it reads low, you could be mashing at a higher temp.  A 90 min. mash will also help to be sure you convert as much of the mash as possible.  1.070 is on the edge of using only pack of yeast, so you might try 2 the next time.

Comment: Ok, sounds good. I like the idea of rice - any special kind of rice (pre-cooked?). I'm not sure what you mean when you say "as a % of fermentables, not weight.", could you clarify?

Comment: You want to replace 10% of the fermentables with an adjunct.  At 75% efficiency, you get about 25 gravity points from a lb. of grain.  Sugar (for instance) gives you about 45 gravity points per lb.  So you'd replace 1 lb. of grain with about 1/2 lb. of sugar.  Corn and rice give you about 40 points per lb.  For rice, I like to use Minute Rice.  The starches in it are already gelatinized so it can go right into the mash.  If you use regular rice, you need to boil it before it goes into the mash.